# Sci-fi story. Survivor ejected in lifepod lands on planet. AI has terraformed the planet to resemble his physiology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Sci-fi story from late 90's or early 2000's collection book that was about a starship survivor who is ejected in a lifepod only big enough for himself that has an AI that keeps him in a matrix-like reality as it drifts eons through space.

The story ends with the machine AI landing on a planet with the bio-remains of the survivor, long dead, which the machine has altered through accelerated evolution to create beings that somewhat resemble the long gone spaceship survivor.

This was part of a collection of stories.

Answer (score 6):

It's likely *[Coffins](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47359)* by Robert Reed (1992). Anthologized in [The Best from Fantasy & Science Fiction   A 45th Anniversary Anthology](https://archive.org/details/The_Best_from_Fantasy_Science_Fiction_A_45th_Anniversary_Anthology_1994_ed._Kris/page/n174/mode/1up) (1994, Ferman & Rusch, eds.), pp.153-164. It begins and ends:

> He sits before a projected clerk, confessing his fears.
>
> “You can’t assure my safety. I know this. You can’t tell me that my ship won’t strike a comet or explode on its own. There’s an attrition rate with star travel, isn’t there? It’s got its inherent dangers, and no technology can absolutely guarantee my survival. Am I right?”
>
> The clerk, sculpted from light and designed to nourish confidence, offers an easy smile while nodding. “Your heart,” it offers, “is a chaotic organ, sir. There’s a measurable statistical chance of complete failure sometime during an average thousand-year life span. A tiny chance, but quite real.”

> A factory rises on the barren ground. Humming machinery and molds work night and day, producing new citizens by the thousands.
>
> Launchpads shake, mighty rockets driving skyward.
>
> Most are bound for nearby suns, but a few have a more distant and personal goal — capsules bursting open in deep space, shiny figures like dust en route to the ancestor’s homeland.
>
> Multitude and the computer are eventually destroyed in an industrial accident, an experimental plasma drill all but evaporating both of them. And the others, following strict instructions, take what remains to the sea and let the tides take them away. Human faces weep. Human voices sing a light, almost happy song from some vanished world called lo. Then it’s back to work, to life, much to be done and the possibilities without number.

Comment: answer via [Ask MetaFilter](https://ask.metafilter.com/329136/Help-me-identify-this-science-fiction-short-story), where this question has been bugging people for [years](https://metatalk.metafilter.com/26071/Still-wondering-after-all-these-years#1401864).

Comment: Excellent!  This does indeed fit the question very well.

Comment: And welcome back!

Comment: The story was originally published in *The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction*, December 1992, and it can be read at [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v083n06_1992-12_EXciter-dtsg0318/page/n58/mode/1up)

Comment: thanks, @DavidW - I knew about the IA link, but didn't know what the protocol was here about linking. There's a cleaner copy in IA's scan of [The Best from Fantasy & Science Fiction   A 45th Anniversary Anthology (1994)](https://archive.org/details/The_Best_from_Fantasy_Science_Fiction_A_45th_Anniversary_Anthology_1994_ed._Kris/page/n174/mode/1up) , which is why I mentioned it over the 1992 original publication in my answer

Comment: Links to IA are fine here; you can include that in your answer.  Also, since the others you identified as likely duplicates don't have this as an answer, you should post your answer on them as well (you might choose to quote different parts of the story, based on the details of the question).  Note that you can't usually copy text for quotes from books on IA, but you almost always can from magazines.

Comment: @DavidW - noted. The text I pasted did come from the book: most IA books (and I've contributed a lot) end up with decent OCR

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat similar to the episode *Rimmerworld* from the TV series *Red Dwarf*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rimmerworld

While the ship is in danger, coward Rimmer takes the only escape pod and ejects.  He lands on a barren planet and Teraforms it, creating       a population cloned from his own DNA.

The two creators of the show fell out, and dissolved their partnership. Both of them wrote novels based on the show, but in separate continuities. I don't know if either of them included this episode in their novels.

Comment: Rimmerworld doesn't appear in any of the authorised script books