# Short story: astronaut travels through space locked in a "spacesuit coffin"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In this short story, probably from the late 70's/early 80's, an astronaut ejects from his ship in a specially designed suit with a computer and life support that keeps him alive, though basically immobile in the suit, his entire remaining life which he lives traveling through the void of space. The computer ends up cloning him after he dies -- not sure about the rest of the story.

Does anyone know the name, author, and book of short stories that this story appeared in?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SFF.SE :) I've taken the liberty to edit your title, in order to make it more explicit. Feel free to edit it again, of course! As for your answer, maybe you could add more details based on [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)? EDIT: given that I don't have the edit privilege, it could take some time to be peer reviewed and accepted. The guide part of this comment still works though :)

Comment: I found a story-id question from 2016 that I think is the same as mine: "Sci-fi story from late 90's or early 2000's collection book that was about a starship survivor who is ejected in a lifepod only big enough for himself that has an AI that keeps him in a matrix-like reality as it drifts eons through space.

The story ends with the machine AI landing on a planet with the bio-remains of the survivor, long dead, which the machine has altered through accelerated evolution to create beings that somewhat resemble the long gone spaceship survivor.

This was part of a collection of stories."

Comment: This one; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148369/sci-fi-story-survivor-ejected-in-lifepod-lands-on-planet-ai-has-terraformed-th

Comment: Was the ejection voluntary? That is, did he *want* to eject and explore the cosmos, or was this more of a case of an emergency ejection that left him effectively marooned in space?

Comment: I don't recall if the ejection was voluntary, but I don't think so.  I think it was an emergency ejection that left him to live out his life in the suit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sci-fi story. Survivor ejected in lifepod lands on planet. AI has terraformed the planet to resemble his physiology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148369/sci-fi-story-survivor-ejected-in-lifepod-lands-on-planet-ai-has-terraformed-th)

Comment: @scruss ditto my last comment although in this case it is somewhat unclear what should be done. As the user believes the linked duplicate to be the same question but suggested so at a time before there were any answers so we can't be certain.

Comment: I read something like this quite recently. The pilot was a survivor of a galactic war. He goes into hypersleep and wakes millions of years into the future, long after all participants are likely to have died. The ship is basically traveling around the galaxy 
assessing planets. It refuses to let him commit suicide and basically freezes him in the ship. At the very end of the story, it lets him leave for Earth (e.g. a planet that meets the requirements for life). If memory serves, it clones him and sets off again on a tour of the galaxy.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe *[Coffins](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47359)* by Robert Reed (1992)? Anthologized in [The Best from Fantasy & Science Fiction   A 45th Anniversary Anthology](https://archive.org/details/The_Best_from_Fantasy_Science_Fiction_A_45th_Anniversary_Anthology_1994_ed._Kris/page/n174/mode/1up) (1994, Ferman & Rusch, eds.), pp.153-164.

Excerpt:

> A little short of his thousandth birthday, he dies. And the griefless computer watches the peaceful failure of organs and the ancient brain. It’s done its primary job as well as possible; it contemplates the silence within and without. But life persists even now. Bacteria begin to feed on the corpse, harvesting its latent energies. Dozens of species thrive, and the computer consciously helps them with warmth and oxygen. Dead tissues become a living goo. The entire body is eradicated, bones dissolving and then the hard white teeth. The goo is fed sugars and amino acids made by the recyke systems. The computer uses its autodoc needles to ensure fair shares to everyone. And it learns as it works, discovering which species prefer which treats, then moving on with the man’s strange, patient plan.